# How does an SQL DB compare integers with stored strings, especially when using ranges / BETWEEN?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

So, I have a DB field zip_code which is a string. Then I attempted to compare this string field with integers that I input (just to see what happens), and all sorts of strange things started to happen:

All the assertions here will be true:

```
User.destroy_all
User.create!(zip_code: "0056") # zip_code is a string in the schema.rb
User.create!(zip_code: "0473")
User.create!(zip_code: "5")
assert_equal 3, User.all.count

assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code = 0').count 
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (zip_code = 0)"

assert_equal 3, User.where('zip_code > 0').count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (zip_code > 0)"

assert_equal 2, User.where('zip_code < 1').count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (zip_code < 1)"
# ["0056", "0473"]
# Question 1: So is "0056" and "0473" interpreted as 0 with decimals? Why are they interpreted as between 0 and 1?

assert_equal 2, User.where('zip_code >= 0 AND zip_code <= 20000').count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (zip_code >= 0 AND zip_code <= 20000)"
# ["0056", "0473"]
# Question 2: Why isn't the user with zip_code "5" included here?

assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code >= 1 AND zip_code <= 20000').count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (zip_code >= 1 AND zip_code <= 20000)"
# []
# Question 3: Why is none of the users found here?

assert_equal 2, User.where(zip_code: 0..20000).count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (\"users\".\"zip_code\" BETWEEN 0 AND 20000)"
# ["0056", "0473"]
# Question 4: Why isn't the user with zip_code "5" included here?

assert_equal 0, User.where(zip_code: 1..20000).count
# "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (\"users\".\"zip_code\" BETWEEN 1 AND 20000)"
# []
# Question 5: Why is none of the users found here?
```

Why? Can someone explain this behavior? What is it about the comparison between string and integer in the SQL DB that is causing this behavior?

For the record: I am using SQLite, Rails 4.1.16, and ruby 2.3.1p112 in these tests.

Comment: String sorting is different from numerical sorting.  `1`, `11`, `111`, `1111`, etc. are all sorted before `2` using string sorting logic.  Numerical sorting is as you would expect: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` all come before `11`.  This is not limited to SQL.  If you don't want string sorting, don't store them as strings.  Otherwise, you'll need to cast them as an `INT`.

Comment: @Siyual Ok, so what is happening is that the integer I input in the query is implicitly cast to a string, and then the two strings are compared? Furthermore "0056" is sorted before "1" because it would just take the first character of the former, so "0" and compare it to the first character of the latter "1" and that is the reason it gives true? That would explain my questions atleast..

Comment: More or less, yes.

Comment: It also seems that it always converts the input integer to the same type as the field in the DB, not the other way around: "If one operand has TEXT affinity and the other has no affinity, then TEXT affinity is applied to the other operand." http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order) says:

> An INTEGER or REAL value is less than any TEXT or BLOB value.

Comment: Thanks, but then shouldn't `User.where('zip_code < 1').count` have returned `0` instead of `2` ?

Comment: It seems the answer lies in this sentence here, in my case: `If one operand has TEXT affinity and the other has no affinity, then TEXT affinity is applied to the other operand.` in Section 4.2. http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: So is "0056" and "0473" interpreted as 0 with decimals? Why are they interpreted as between 0 and 1?

No. They the value 1 being compared to is converted to a string, and then they are compared, bytewise from left to right. Thus, because the first char (`'0'`) in those strings are `< '1'` then they are included in the result.

> Question 2: Why isn't the user with zip_code "5" included here?

Because, again, the first char in the strings `'5'` is not `<=` than the first char in the string `'20000'` which is `'2'`.

> Question 3: Why is none of the users found here?

Because the first char in the zip codes '0056' and '0473' is `'0'` and that is not `>= '1'`. Also, the first char in the zip code `'5'` is not `>= '2'` (which is the first char in `'20000'`).

> Question 4: Why isn't the user with zip_code "5" included here?

Same answer as for question 2. Actually the select statement in question 2 is what SQLite will convert this BETWEEN statement to.*

> Question 5: Why is none of the users found here?

Same answer as for question 3. Actually the select statement in question 3 is what SQLite will convert this BETWEEN statement to.*

Here is some working code, with explanations, demonstrating how SQLite will make sucha comparison concept:

```rb
# All the following assertions evaluate to true.
# Gotcha: The integer 0473 will actually be "315" in string, because 0473.to_s => 315 . So never do '.where(zip_code: 0473)' because it will fail silently. Remember to wrap the zip code in "".
assert_equal 1, User.where(zip_code: '0473').count # this is correct: what is in the users.yml
# Demonstrates the gotcha
assert_equal 0, User.where(zip_code: 473).count
assert_equal 0, User.where(zip_code: 0473).count # The SQL will be "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE \"users\".\"zip_code\" = 315"
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code = 0473').count
assert_equal "315", 0473.to_s
u = User.create!(zip_code: "315") # unintended user
# This will also actually match the unintended user!
assert_equal 1, User.where(zip_code: 0473).count
# This will actually not match the unintended user.
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code = 0473').count

# Will also fail similarly for ranges:
u.destroy
assert_equal 0, User.where(zip_code: 472..474).count
assert_equal 0, User.where(zip_code: 0472..0474).count # This will actually be interpreted in SQL as 314..316 like this: "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (\"users\".\"zip_code\" BETWEEN 314 AND 316)"
assert_equal "315", 0473.to_s
u = User.create!(zip_code: "315") # unintended user
# This will also actually match the unintended user!
assert_equal 1, User.where(zip_code: 0472..0474).count

# Will also fail similarly for ranges, and fail in another unexpected way if the range is specified in raw SQL
u.destroy
assert_equal 1, User.where(zip_code: '0473').count # this is correct: what is in the users.yml
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code BETWEEN 472 AND 474').count
# Section 4.3 in https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html :
# Because column "zip_code" has text affinity, numeric values on the
# -- right-hand side of the comparisons are converted to text before
# -- the comparison occurs.
# Gotcha: Before comparison with the string in the DB which is '0473', then SQLite will convert the input 0472 like this:
# - first strip any leading zeroes in the integer: 0472 -> 472
# - convert the resulting integer/number to a string: 472 -> '472'
# - compare, from left to right the characters in the two strings ('0473' >= '472') which gives:
#   - '0' >= '4' which is false, thus stop further comparison
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code >= 0472').count
# Gotcha: The following compares exising DB values '0056' and '0473' with '474', char by char from left to right
# - '0' <= '4', which is true, thus stop further comparison (because it uses memcmp() which compares the first n bytes of each string). and include '0056' to the result.
# - '0' <= '4', which is true, thus stop further comparison, and include '0473' to the result.
assert_equal 2, User.where('zip_code <= 0474').count
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code BETWEEN 0472 AND 0474').count
# Section 4.2 in https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html : The expression "a BETWEEN b AND c" is treated as two separate binary comparisons "a >= b AND a <= c"
assert_equal 0, User.where('zip_code >= 0472 AND zip_code <= 0474').count
```

Footnote:
*

> *The expression "a BETWEEN b AND c" is treated as two separate binary
>   comparisons "a >= b AND a <= c"*

Source: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison